# get json object from php to angularjs and print it without duplicate errors

Tags: php, angularjs, json

```
https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/{contry code}/.json
```

this is the content i get from my moudle in php and i want to print this list in angular so i can live update it

```
app.controller('list', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/mvcang/list_it/sell/SWISH')
    .then(function(response) {

        $scope.values = response.data.profile;
    });
});
```

this is the angular code i use to get the info from my localhost

how do i do so it prints the list i get dublicate error and when i do .profile i get nothing!

have any idées or solutions please help:D

Comment: {contry code} means like usd and etc

Comment: update your post with the sample **get request** and **json** output. Also {contry code} in your URL is it passed as a parameter?

Comment: i allready pass the verable i need to get the info from it in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('list', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
  $interval(function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost/mvcang/list_it/sell/SWISH')
    .then(function(data) {
      data = data.data;
      if($scope.phones != data){

        $scope.phones = data;
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

worked it out it way a that i didnt understand that it was data in the json object